# Paste text as keystrokes

Tags: shell, vmware

Is there an easy way to send copied text as keystrokes as many of the machines I cannot paste into the remote computers?

I am using a windows 10 workstation to connect to a VMWare player Linux guest then through a VPN to another windows 7 computer at a remote site. I am able to paste from the Linux machine into the windows computer but can only pass keystrokes to the VMware player, no copy and paste. I am also prevented form allowing the VM from accessing the local network. I am using a 16GB USB drive to pass files back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly :

Workstation W10 -> Linux VM ? -> W7 VM ?

If so, you need to make sure you have vmware tools on all the VMs for copy paste to work